Azure Web App Docker container keeps getting redownloaded
I have an Azure Web App with a Docker container deployed from an Azure Container Registry. Once in awhile when I go to access my webapp it shows that it's downloading and extracting a "newer image" for the same container again. According to the logs it's done this 8 times within the last 24 hours, but according to the container registry the container hasn't been updated since last month. Why is it doing this and how can I stop it? It's causing my app to be constantly offline.
Here is an example log:
2024-06-11T02:04:08.005Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Downloading 1777MB / 4415MB
2024-06-11T02:04:08.097Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Downloading 1788MB / 4415MB
...
2024-06-11T02:04:33.397Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Downloading 4358MB / 4415MB
2024-06-11T02:04:33.841Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Verifying Checksum
2024-06-11T02:04:33.842Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Download complete
2024-06-11T02:04:34.103Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Extracting 544KB / 4415MB
2024-06-11T02:04:34.212Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Extracting 2MB / 4415MB
...
2024-06-11T02:08:03.882Z INFO - 37be3bacfb45 Pull complete
2024-06-11T02:08:03.959Z INFO - Digest: sha256:b6e72dbc016f5bd0c21947b353854fc7516510bd5964dcf9139b0218ea20f326
2024-06-11T02:08:03.962Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T02:08:03.996Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 271 Seconds
2024-06-11T02:08:04.577Z INFO - Starting container for site
2024-06-11T02:08:04.577Z INFO - docker run -d --expose=4200 --name mydemo_0_fd507ee6 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myDemo -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=True -e PORT=4200 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=mydemo.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8208f53149922e3976919b315d79cc0270505b7c74ab97488e790c1dc2b950f0 mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0 /bin/bash /data/gitclone/myDemo/FrontEnd/start.sh
2024-06-11T02:08:04.577Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2024-06-11T02:08:08.799Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container mydemo_0_fd507ee6_msiProxy for site mydemo
2024-06-11T02:08:08.866Z INFO - Container mydemo_0_fd507ee6_msiProxy for site mydemo initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2024-06-11T02:08:08.866Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container mydemo_0_fd507ee6 for site mydemo
2024-06-11T02:08:59.970Z INFO - Container mydemo_0_fd507ee6 for site mydemo initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2024-06-11T02:08:59.970Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container mydemo_0_fd507ee6_middleware for site mydemo
2024-06-11T02:09:00.224Z INFO - Container mydemo_0_fd507ee6_middleware for site mydemo initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2024_06_11_pl1mdlwk000CGP_docker.log:
2024-06-11T04:43:11.100Z INFO - c153187b164d Downloading 1129MB / 1558MB
2024-06-11T04:43:11.101Z INFO - e5cb4ff8283c Downloading 1243MB / 4415MB
...

Just looking at the timestamps for how often a "newer image" has been downloaded, it seems this has happened 8 times over the last 24h.
2024-06-11T00:49:48.476Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T02:08:03.962Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T04:46:57.822Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T06:08:13.868Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T07:26:34.664Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T08:44:46.129Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T18:43:03.239Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0
2024-06-11T20:02:01.164Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycontainer.azurecr.io/mydemo:v3.0

The container registry says this container hasn't been updated in over a month. (Today's date is 6/11).

This is what my deployment center looks like:

--
Edit: I do not use a Dockerfile for this webapp, but there does exist a Dockerfile in a subdirectory that is used for an unrelated project. This Docker container was built manually by pulling a copy of the node container from DockerHub, git cloning my code, and pushing the container.
Here is the file structure and the contents of the other Dockerfile:
mydemo (top level of git repo)
|__ FrontEnd
    |__ start.sh (entry point for this web app)
    |__ other frontend files
|__ BackEnd (used for another web app, but files are pulled anyways as part of the git repo)
    |__ Dockerfile
    |__ other backend files

# Use the latest Windows Server Core 2022 image.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Copy build files into the container.
COPY SDWebServer/ Users/Administrator/Downloads/Models/SDWebServer/

# Install chocolatey.
RUN powershell -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install Python version 3.9. DO NOT UPGRADE OR IT WILL BREAK DOCMRC.
RUN choco install -y python3 --version 3.9

# Install requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r Users/Administrator/Downloads/Models/SDWebServer/requirements.txt

# Expose port 9090
EXPOSE 9090

--
Edit 2:
Retention policy is disabled on my container and I cannot get premium policy to turn it on.


can you share your Dockerfile for more detail.

there is no dockerfile used to build this portion of the webapp, but there is a dockerfile in a subdirectory related to a separate project. could that be interfering? i've posted the other dockerfile

Here I clear that your web App doesn't use a Dockerfile and instead relies on pulling an image from Azure Container Registry. can you please share the image that you have in the ACR.

Are there any latest updates to that image within this month gap? and the image pull policy for the Web App should ideally set to IfNotPresent or Never to avoid pulling the image unnecessarily. If it's set to Always, it will always try to pull the image regardless of whether it exists locally or not.

I cannot share the image because it contains company code :( I believe there are no updates within the month gap, because the "last modified" date should have changed if there were

Where do I find the image pull policy to check the value?

In a Dockerfile, it specifies how the Docker image is built. Once an image is built and pushed to a registry like ACR, Dockerfiles do not control when an image is redownloaded by itself. Dockerfiles primarily define the build process, dependencies, and execution environment of the application.

Azure App Service may restart the containers for various reasons such as updates, scaling events, or maintenance. Each restart can trigger a pull of the latest specified image.


Just looking at the timestamps for how often a "newer image" has been downloaded, it seems this has happened 8 times over the last 24h.

Redownloading periodically or based on a schedule is not a standard feature of Dockerfiles or Azure App Service settings
Redownloading behavior is usually driven by Azure Container Registry (ACR) Policies.

The retention policy in ACR determines how long an image is retained before it's deleted. If an older image is deleted due to this policy, Azure App Service would pull the latest available image on the next restart.you can check the same in MS_DOC.

Here, you need to disable the retention policy or else extend the period.




I edited the end of my post to show my container retention policy. It seems I cannot edit this because I do not have premium. I assume this means this cannot be the cause of my bootloop?
